# I have multidimensional array in php and want to remove duplicate entries on the basis of 3 column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this and I want to unique it on basis of `sender_id`, `receiver_id` and `classifieds_id` if these 3 columns are matched in 2 array then I want to remove old one on basis of created column if any 2 column matched nothing will happen only on matched of 3 column array will be removed

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 131826 [user_id] => 131826 [1] => 131826 [sender_id] => 131826 [2] => 141332 [receiver_id] => 141332 [3] => 1055971 [classifieds_id] => 1055971 [4] => 1 [status] => 1 [5] => 2016-04-07 12:37:42 [created] => 2016-04-07 12:37:42 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 141332 [user_id] => 141332 [1] => 141332 [sender_id] => 141332 [2] => 131826 [receiver_id] => 131826 [3] => 1055971 [classifieds_id] => 1055971 [4] => 1 [status] => 1 [5] => 2016-04-07 12:30:06 [created] => 2016-04-07 12:30:06 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 141332 [user_id] => 141332 [1] => 141332 [sender_id] => 141332 [2] => 131826 [receiver_id] => 131826 [3] => 1055971 [classifieds_id] => 1055971 [4] => 1 [status] => 1 [5] => 2016-04-07 12:28:32 [created] => 2016-04-07 12:28:32 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 131826 [user_id] => 131826 [1] => 131826 [sender_id] => 131826 [2] => 141332 [receiver_id] => 141332 [3] => 1055971 [classifieds_id] => 1055971 [4] => 1 [status] => 1 [5] => 2016-04-06 12:28:53 [created] => 2016-04-06 12:28:53 ) 
)
```

Comment: it is better, if you add up the array used, instead of `print_r()` output. and even what have you tried, post that as well.

Comment: I just want to remove duplicate entries from array on basis of sender_id, receiver_id and classifieds_id

Comment: my question is, what have you tried to achieve your result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick way by building composite keys that will remove duplicates.  But first sort by date descending so that oldest are first and will be overwritten in the loop.  If it is a SQL query and you can order it in the query then the sort is not needed:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'created'), SORT_DESC, $array);

foreach($array as $v) {
    $result[$v['sender_id'].'-'.$v['receiver_id'].'-'.$v['classifieds_id']] = $v;
}

// if you want to re-index
$result = array_values($result);
```

Actually, if this is a database query there may be a way to `SELECT DISTINCT` but a SQL guru will need to answer that one.

Comment: this would be a problem when you have two records with 100,111,121 this forms a key like `100111121` and the other record with values 1001,111,21 this will also form a key as `100111121` and will be overwritten.

Comment: yeah, thats great.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering your Array as follows.

```
$classifiedArr[]    = array("user_id" => "131826", "sender_id" => "131826", "receiver_id" => "141332", "classifieds_id" => "1055971", "status" => "1", "created" => "2016-04-07 12:37:42");
$classifiedArr[]    = array("user_id" => "141332", "sender_id" => "141332", "receiver_id" => "131826", "classifieds_id" => "1055971", "status" => "1", "created" => "2016-04-07 12:30:06");
$classifiedArr[]    = array("user_id" => "141332", "sender_id" => "141332", "receiver_id" => "131826", "classifieds_id" => "1055971", "status" => "1", "created" => "2016-04-07 12:28:32");
$classifiedArr[]    = array("user_id" => "131826", "sender_id" => "131826", "receiver_id" => "141332", "classifieds_id" => "1055971", "status" => "1", "created" => "2016-04-06 12:28:53");

foreach($classifiedArr as $indClassified) {
    $createUnique   = $indClassified["user_id"]."|".$indClassified["sender_id"]."|".$indClassified["receiver_id"];
    $newArray[$createUnique]    = $indClassified;
}
```

logic is simple and self-explanatory, here i created a new Array, which holds unique array key with combination of `user_id - sender_id - receiver_id`.